# How to send multiple records using post method from iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, post, methods

I need some help on sending multiple records using http POST method . I have a database in my iPhone with fields like StudentName,Semester,TotalMarks,Grade . 
Each record consist of values for each of the above mentioned fields . There can be more than 500 records and i want to send the information to server using POST method . Can anyone help me out how to achieve this ?

Snippet of code will be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to bundle the data up in a JSON file and submit it as a posted form value. Explore one of the many JSON libraries (I like JSON Framework, but I'm not religious about it) and ASIHTTPRequest for posting the HTTP request (which I *am* religious about).

There are way too many possible starting points for any code suggestion to make any sense. If you show us where you're starting from in YOUR code, though, we can help from there.